# What is the difference between cin>>gender and cin>>*gender ( c-style text string)

Tags: c++

I dynamically allocated memory for variable gender that is c-style text string. After that, I initialized temp_g1 and temp_g2 so that, I can make sufficient comparison in while loop, which will compare, if inputted gender is valid or not. So when you compile the program, I am a little confused because, when I use cin as cin>>gender there is no problem and everything works fine but with cin>>*gender, comparison is not done as it should.

Here is code and note that I used cin>>*gender.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char *gender = new char[2];
    const char temp_g1[2] = "M";
    const char temp_g2[2] = "F";


    cout << "Enter gender(M/F): "; cin >> *gender;

    while (stricmp(gender, temp_g1) != 0 && stricmp(gender, temp_g2) != 0) {
        cout << "Error\n";
        cout << "Enter gender: "; cin >> *gender;
    }

    delete[]gender; gender = nullptr;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not null-terminating `gender`. After doing `cin >> *gender`, do `gender[1] = 0`.

Comment: When you have one letter, consider using a single `char` instead of a C-style (or C++ style) string. Less overhead and much simpler comparison .

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the title:

`cin >> *gender` writes a character to the first byte of `gender`.

`cin >> gender` writes a properly null-terminated C string to `gender`.

However, the specific problem you're having is caused by the fact that you're not null-terminating `gender`.

After doing

```
cin >> *gender;
```

you should null-terminate the string by doing

```
gender[1] = 0;
```